# How to convert SQL Server's timestamp column to datetime format

Tags: sql-server, datetime, timestamp

As SQL Server returns timestamp like `'Nov 14 2011 03:12:12:947PM'`, is there some easy way to convert string to date format like 'Y-m-d H:i:s'.

So far I use

```
date('Y-m-d H:i:s',strtotime('Nov 14 2011 03:12:12:947PM'))
```

Answer (score 298, accepted):

SQL Server's `TIMESTAMP` datatype has **nothing** to do with a date and time!

It's just a hexadecimal representation of a consecutive 8 byte integer - it's only good for making sure a row hasn't change since it's been read.

You can read off the hexadecimal integer or if you want a `BIGINT`. As an example:

```
SELECT CAST (0x0000000017E30D64 AS BIGINT)
```

The result is

```
400756068
```

In newer versions of SQL Server, it's being called `RowVersion` - since that's really what it is. See the [MSDN docs on ROWVERSION](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182776.aspx):

> *Is a data type that exposes automatically generated, unique binary numbers within a database. rowversion is generally used as a mechanism
>   for version-stamping table rows. The
>   rowversion data type is **just an incrementing number and does not
>   preserve a date or a time**. To record a date or time, use a datetime2
>   data type.*

So you **cannot** convert a SQL Server `TIMESTAMP` to a date/time - it's just not a date/time.

But if you're saying timestamp but really you mean a `DATETIME` column - then you can use any of those valid date formats described in the [CAST and CONVERT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx) topic in the MSDN help. Those are defined and supported "out of the box" by SQL Server. Anything else is not supported, e.g. you have to do a lot of manual casting and concatenating (not recommended).

The format you're looking for looks a bit like the *ODBC canonical* (style = 121):

```
DECLARE @today DATETIME = SYSDATETIME()

SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(50), @today, 121)
```

gives:

```
2011-11-14 10:29:00.470
```

[SQL Server 2012 will finally have a `FORMAT` function](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2011/09/17/sql-server-denali-string-function-format-a-quick-introduction/) to do custom formatting......

Comment: Probably my biggest peeve with SQL Server. Why call it a timestamp if I cannot tell the time with it?

Comment: @BelgoCanadian: ask Sybase - that's a feature that's been in Sybase/SQL Server forever .....

Comment: @BelgoCanadian You should be glad to know it is now called rowversion https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/rowversion-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017

Comment: there are `TIMESTAMP` type columns

Comment: Incorrect. It is literally a DATE, with a TIME tailed to it. https://stackoverflow.com/a/63586260

Answer (score 7):

The simplest way of doing this is:

```
SELECT id,name,FROM_UNIXTIME(registration_date) FROM `tbl_registration`;
```

This gives the date column atleast in a readable format.
Further if you want to change te format click [here](https://www.w3resource.com/mysql/date-and-time-functions/mysql-from_unixtime-function.php).

Comment: the question is SQLServer,  not MySQL

Answer (score 6):

Works fine, except this message:

> Implicit conversion from data type varchar to timestamp is not allowed. Use the CONVERT function to run this query

So yes, `TIMESTAMP` (`RowVersion`) is **NOT** a DATE :)

To be honest, I fidddled around quite some time myself to find a way to convert it to a date.

Best way is to convert it to `INT` and compare. That's what this type is meant to be.

If you want a date - just add a `Datetime` column and live happily ever after :)

cheers mac

Comment: Or BIGINT since it is 8 bytes

Answer (score 4):

Using cast you can get date from a timestamp field:

```
SELECT CAST(timestamp_field AS DATE) FROM tbl_name
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to work: `Explicit conversion from data type timestamp to date is not allowed.`

Comment: Bad idea. The timestamp field is just a sequence. You might get lucky and get a date, but the date will have no meaning. You should cast to BIGINT if you want a decimal number, rather than hex. Timestamp is now called rowversion https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/rowversion-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017

Answer (score 3):

My coworkers helped me with this:

```
select CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), <tms_column>, 112), count(*)
from table where <tms_column> > '2012-09-10'
group by CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), <tms_column>, 112);
```

or

```
select CONVERT(DATE, <tms_column>, 112), count(*)
from table where <tms_column> > '2012-09-10'
group by CONVERT(DATE, <tms_column>, 112);
```

Answer (score 3):

"You keep using that word. I do not think it means what you think it means."
— Inigo Montoya

The timestamp has absolutely no relationship to time as marc_s originally said.

```
declare @Test table (
     TestId int identity(1,1) primary key clustered
    ,Ts     timestamp
    ,CurrentDt datetime default getdate()
    ,Something varchar(max)
)

insert into @Test (Something)
    select name from sys.tables
waitfor delay '00:00:10'

insert into @Test (Something)
    select name from sys.tables

select * from @Test
```

Notice in the output that Ts (hex) increments by one for each record, but the actual time has a gap of 10 seconds.  If it were related to time then there would be a gap in the timestamp to correspond with the difference in the time.

Answer (score 1):

Robert Mauro has the correct comment.  For those who know the Sybase origins, datetime was really two separate integers, one for date, one for time, so timestamp aka rowversion could just be considered the raw value captured from the server.  Much faster.

Comment: might be worth linking the comment in your answer :)

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30119305)

Comment: @PaulBenn he refers to my answer, for some reason downvoted to heck, which is odd, because it's (a) correct, (b) works, and (c) explains why. Literally every upvoted answer that says it's not possible is the wrong one. 

https://stackoverflow.com/a/63586260

Comment: @ADyson you'd be surprised at how many times MS Learn materials are wrong. I literally used my method on *MS* SQL databases and it works fine, because, it is literally patterned off a Sybase date time representation. When MS bought SQL Server, they forgot a lot. SQL Server was Sybase. If you try to do a cast conversion places I never suggested to do it, then, yeah, things will blow up, like they did for you. Take the column as hex data, then follow my instructions. I've been doing database stuff since b4 MS knew what they were - back in the mid 80's using Sybase, dBase, mainframe, more.

Answer (score 0):

After impelemtation of conversion to integer
CONVERT(BIGINT, [timestamp]) as Timestamp
I've got the result like

> 446701117 
>   446701118 
>   446701119 
>   446701120 
>   446701121 
>   446701122
>   446701123
>   446701124 
>   446701125 
>   446701126

Yes, this is not a date and time, It's serial numbers

Answer (score 0):

for me works:
TO_DATE('19700101', 'yyyymmdd') + (TIME / 24 / 60 / 60)
(oracle DB)

Comment: the question is for SQLServer, not MySQ