# Using timestamp from sqlserver in entity framework to only get changes rather then reloading whole table/view

Tags: c#, sql-server, winforms, entity-framework, sql-server-2008-r2

I would like to have optimized version of my WinForms C# based application for slower connections. For this reason I wanted to introduce `timestamp` column into all tables (that change) and load most of things the first time it's needed and then just read updates/inserts/deletes that could have been done by other people using application.

For this question to have an example I've added a `timestamp` column into Table called `Konsultanci`. Considering that this table might be large I would like to load it once and then check for updates/inserts. In a simple way to load it all I do it like this:

```
    private void KonsultantsListFill(ObjectListView listView)
    {
        using (var context = new EntityBazaCRM(Settings.sqlDataConnectionDetailsCRM)) {

            ObjectSet<Konsultanci> listaKonsultantow = context.Konsultancis;
            GlobalnaListaKonsultantow = listaKonsultantow.ToList(); // assign to global variable to be used all around the WinForms code.
        }
    }
```

How would I go with checking if anything changed to the table? Also how do I handle updates in `WinForms c#`? Should I be checking for changes on each `tabpage` select, opening new gui's, saving, loading of clients, consultants and so on? Should I be refreshing all tables all the time (like firing a background thread that is executed every single action that user does? or should it only be executed prior to eventual need for the data).

What I'm looking here is:

1. General advice on how to approach timestamp problem and refreshing data without having to load everything multiple times (slow connection issues)
2. A code example with Entity Framework considering timestamp column? Eventually code to be used prior executing something that requires data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Timestamps are not well suited to help you detect when your cache needs to be updated.  First off, they are not datetimes ([read here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8119386/how-to-convert-sql-servers-timestamp-column-to-datetime-format)) so they don't give you any clue as to when a record was updated.  Timestamps are geared more towards assisting in optimistic locking and concurrency control, not cache management. When trying to update your cache you need a mechanism like a LastModified datetime field on your tables (make sure it's indexed!) and then a mechanism to periodically check for rows that have been modified since the last time you checked.

Regarding keeping your data fresh, you could run a separate query (possibly on another thread) that finds all records with the LastModified > than the last time you checked and then "upsert" (update or insert) them into your cache context.  Another mechanism with Entity Framework is to use the [Context.Refresh() method.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb896255.aspx)

Comment: Context.Refresh() won't work for me as I disconnect from Context when I get data of SQL. So this has to be something alone the lines you mentioned. Thanks for explanation that Timestamp isn't good for my needs.