# Retrieving current timestamp of the database

Tags: sql-server, linq, entity-framework

Is there a way to get the last updated/current timestamp (or counter which causes timestamps of the table rows to increment.) of a database using LINQ or Entity Framework ?

Comment: Just execute `SELECT GETDATE()` ?!?!?

Comment: Ah! I'm not talking about the datetime datatype. I'm asking for the timestamp datatype.

Comment: `TIMESTAMP` has **nothing** to do with date and/or time - you cannot get the "current" `TIMESTAMP`  since there is no such thing as a "current" `TIMESTAMP`. This is simply a consecutive numerical value that SQL Server handles - and you cannot "read out" the "current" value - that doesn't exist. SQL Server will automatically set the `TIMESTAMP` when a row is modified in any way

Comment: that's why I mentioned last updated/current :) . Isn't there a way to get it, so I could later check table rows with it to compare for modifications???

Comment: [See this other SO question on the same topic](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8119386/how-to-convert-sql-servers-timestamp-column-to-datetime-format)

Comment: You can select the `TIMESTAMP` column from a given table/row - and then compare it later - yes. But there's no global "current timestamp". A `TIMESTAMP` column is typically represented as a byte array in Linq-to-SQL or EF

Comment: Yep. I understand it has nothing to do with time. that's why I asked for the counter or something like that, for the purpose I mentioned in the earlier comment.

Comment: I thought of syncing by first sending a timestamp to the other side and when the next sync comes, getting that timestamp and compare with the table rows. Can you tell me how can I use timestamp for this scenario ?

Answer (score 1):

See http://www.sqlnotes.info/2012/04/13/dbts-vs-min_active_rowversion/ . To get the latest used timestamp (aka rowversion) in any committed transaction run:

```
select @@dbts
```

Answer (score 0):

In Linq-to-SQL - you can use the [`ExecuteQuery` method on the `DataContext`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb361109.aspx):

```
DateTime currentDateTime = 
   ctx.ExecuteQuery<DateTime>("SELECT GETDATE()", new object[] {}).FirstOrDefault();
```

Something similar ought to be possible in Entity Framework, too ([ObjectContext.ExecuteStoreQuery](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd487208.aspx))