# Order by SQL timestamp

Tags: sql, sql-order-by

I have a timestamp field added to every of my records with an SQL timestamp, (yes, the format is actually TIMESTAMP). I want to display my records by date and time; can I just ORDER BY in an SQL statement?

```
SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY timestamp DESC
```

Comment: Assuming you say *SQL* but really mean **SQL Server**: the `TIMESTAMP` datatype has **nothing** to do with a date and/or a time. But it is a sequentially increasing number (a `ROWVERSION` - that's it's new and more appropriate name), so ordering by it will order by the sequence of changes to the rows.

Comment: Try having a look at this SO question:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8119386/how-to-convert-sql-servers-timestamp-column-to-datetime-format

Comment: Of course you can: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!12/da966/1

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it has been abandoned without the OP telling us what RDBMS they are using or what problems (if any) they encounter when they try.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming its MySQL,

```
SELECT *
FROM randomTable
ORDER BY timestampfield DESC;
```

is just perfect.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I tried it and it is working for me on Oracl SQL Developer