# How to retrieve DateTime from a Timestamp column in a table in SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I am using following query but it doesn't provide any meaningful output:

```
Select Cast(versionno as bigint) from BranchDetail
```

The value in `Version` column is like this : `0x000000000D2537F7`

Comment: @TimSchmelter No its not. My columns has value like '0x000000000D2537F7'

Comment: But is it a `timestamp` then?

Comment: The hex value converted to a long and interpreted as a unix epoche timestamp yields `Sun, 26 Oct 2081 06:57:52 GM`. Would that be what you expected?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `TIMESTAMP` has nothing to do with date and time.  See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8119386/how-to-convert-sql-servers-timestamp-column-to-datetime-format).  It is a `ROWVERSION`, not a date/time value.