# Timestamp confusion in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a `TimeStamp (varchar(50),null)` column in my SQL Server 2008 table which looks misleading by the name `TimeStamp`. I mean it appears as if it's a datatype timestamp but it's `varchar`.

But it has values like `201403240004` which looks like a date. Can I convert it into date and use?

Read [online](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8119386/how-to-convert-sql-servers-timestamp-column-to-datetime-format) that `timestamp` is only a sequence of numbers and has nothing to do with date and time.

Comment: yeah, you don't want to use `timestamp`, you want a `datetime`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can.

Providing that the format is YYYYMMDDHHmm, a simple way to do that would be:

```
SELECT CONVERT(DATETIME,
   SUBSTRING([TimeStamp],1,4)+'-'+SUBSTRING([TimeStamp],5,2)+'-'
  +SUBSTRING([TimeStamp],7,2)+' '+SUBSTRING([TimeStamp],9,2)+':'
  +SUBSTRING([TimeStamp],11,2)+':00.000')
FROM Table
```

This will take this "timestamp" and first transform it to SQL-readable datetime string, i.e. for your example it would be `2014-03-24 00:04:00.000`. Then, it will be easily converted to datetime.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, your column should be convertible to DATETIME, but you may have to do the converison yourself if CONVERT() does support the format.

I can't tell from you example what the time format really is.

If it is YYYYMMDDHHMM them

```
SELECT CONVERT(DATETIME,LEFT('201403240004',8),112)
      +CONVERT(DATETIME,SUBSTRING('201403240004',9,2)+ ':' + RIGHT('201403240004',2)+':00' ,108)
```