# getting invalid column error in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

I have the following query:

The value in the TimeStamp columns is `201403240004` so the following function converts it in the format: `2014-03-24 00:04:00.000`

```
SELECT CONVERT(DATETIME,
   SUBSTRING([TimeStamp],1,4)+'-'+SUBSTRING([TimeStamp],5,2)+'-'
  +SUBSTRING([TimeStamp],7,2)+' '+SUBSTRING([TimeStamp],9,2)+':'
  +SUBSTRING([TimeStamp],11,2)+':00.000') AS MessageDate
FROM Table
   WHERE MessageDate = '2014-03-24 00:04:00.000'
```

When I am trying to use `MessageDate` in WHERE clause, why do I get invalid column name error in sqlserver? How can I use the converted `MessageDate` in my WHERE clause?

Comment: Is it MySQL or SQL Server?

Comment: Syntax matches SQL Server.

Comment: SQL Server 2008. I am using SQL Server Management studio for running queries.

Comment: @EricHauenstein I know, the query sounds [familiar to me](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23280693/3434221), but the naming here was rather ambiguous.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't really use the column you have just defined. Your options are:

1. Explicitly rewrite the original query (I won't recommend that - too complicated, not too foolproof):

```
SELECT CONVERT(DATETIME,
   SUBSTRING([TimeStamp],1,4)+'-'+SUBSTRING([TimeStamp],5,2)+'-'
  +SUBSTRING([TimeStamp],7,2)+' '+SUBSTRING([TimeStamp],9,2)+':'
  +SUBSTRING([TimeStamp],11,2)+':00.000') AS MessageDate
FROM Table WHERE CONVERT(DATETIME,
   SUBSTRING([TimeStamp],1,4)+'-'+SUBSTRING([TimeStamp],5,2)+'-'
  +SUBSTRING([TimeStamp],7,2)+' '+SUBSTRING([TimeStamp],9,2)+':'
  +SUBSTRING([TimeStamp],11,2)+':00.000') = '2014-03-24 00:04:00.000'
```

1. Insert the data to temporary table (would be a good option if you need to access it more times)
2. My favorite option: Use a [Common Table Expression](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190766%28v=sql.105%29.aspx):

```
;WITH data AS (SELECT CONVERT(DATETIME,
   SUBSTRING([TimeStamp],1,4)+'-'+SUBSTRING([TimeStamp],5,2)+'-'
  +SUBSTRING([TimeStamp],7,2)+' '+SUBSTRING([TimeStamp],9,2)+':'
  +SUBSTRING([TimeStamp],11,2)+':00.000') AS MessageDate
FROM Table
 ) SELECT * FROM data
   WHERE MessageDate = '2014-03-24 00:04:00.000'
```

Comment: What is `;WITH ` ? Is your statement follow the `SELECT` Query  I have used?

Comment: `;WITH` is a Common Table Expression, a really useful thing in MSSQL. I have improved the post now to include a [link](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190766(v=sql.105).aspx) to some details about how to use CTE.

Answer (score 1):

You can't use a computed column directly as the`select`statement is processed after the `where`clause. One way of using the computed column is to wrap it in another select like this:

```
SELECT * FROM (
  SELECT CONVERT(DATETIME,
     SUBSTRING([TimeStamp],1,4)+'-'+SUBSTRING([TimeStamp],5,2)+'-'
    +SUBSTRING([TimeStamp],7,2)+' '+SUBSTRING([TimeStamp],9,2)+':'
    +SUBSTRING([TimeStamp],11,2)+':00.000') AS MessageDate
  FROM Table) innerQuery
WHERE MessageDate = '2014-03-24 00:04:00.000'
```

or you could use the full computation in the where clause.