# SQL Server Timestamp using with C#

Tags: c#, sql-server

In my database I have used `Timestamp` in each table to see when data was inserted.

It stores data in `byte[]` of 8 byte.

Now I want to read that time using C#.

How can I get `DateTime` object from `Timestamp` which is `byte[]`?

Comment: You have a fundamental misunderstanding about that data type. It's not a date or time.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to convert SQL Server's timestamp column to datetime format](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8119386/how-to-convert-sql-servers-timestamp-column-to-datetime-format)

Answer (score 4):

SQL Server's `TIMESTAMP` datatype has **nothing** to do with a date and time!

It's just a binary representation of a consecutive number - it's only good for making sure a row hasn't change since it's been read.

In never versions of SQL Server, it's being called `RowVersion` - since that's really what it is. See the [MSDN docs on ROWVERSION](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182776.aspx):

> *Is a data type that exposes automatically generated, unique binary numbers within a database. rowversion is generally used as a mechanism
>   for version-stamping table rows. The
>   rowversion data type is **just an incrementing number and does not
>   preserve a date or a time**. To record a date or time, use a datetime2
>   data type.*

So you **cannot** convert a SQL Server `TIMESTAMP` to a date/time - it's just not a date/time.

But if you're saying timestamp but really you mean a `DATETIME` column - then you can use any of those valid date formats described in the [CAST and CONVERT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx) topic in the MSDN help. Those are defined and supported "out of the box" by SQL Server. Anything else is not supported, e.g. you have to do a lot of manual casting and concatenating (not recommended).

The format you're looking for looks a bit like the *ODBC canonical* (style = 121):

```
DECLARE @today DATETIME = SYSDATETIME()

SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(50), @today, 121)
```

gives:

```
2011-11-14 10:29:00.470
```

[SQL Server 2012 will finally have a `FORMAT` function](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2011/09/17/sql-server-denali-string-function-format-a-quick-introduction/) to do custom formatting......