# SQL Server Convert Time Stamp in date

Tags: sql, sql-server

Function to get time stamp to date format for example

```
Date Field
2014-06-15 00:00:00.000
```

I want it to show the date as
6/15/2014
in another column call day.

What function do i use in sql server?

Thanks

Comment: take a look at `CONVERT`

Comment: Do you mean `DATETIME`?  The `TIMESTAMP` data type is not directly convertible to a date.

Comment: Potential duplicate : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8119386/how-to-convert-sql-servers-timestamp-column-to-datetime-format ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the source column is of type `Datetime` and target column can be of `varchar` then you can simply write as:

```
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), mydatetimecolumn, 101) AS [MM/DD/YYYY]
From Testtable
```

else if source column is of type `varchar` and you are sure that all dates are valid then you can write as:

```
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), cast('2014-06-15 00:00:00.000' as datetime),
101) AS [MM/DD/YYYY]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Select Convert(Varchar,Convert(Date,'2014-06-15 00:00:00.000'),110)
```

Answer (score 0):

### For SQL 2012 and above:

```
DECLARE @TimeStamp DATETIME = '2014-06-15 00:00:00.000'

SELECT FORMAT(@TimeStamp,'d','en-US') AS Format_Date
```

Results:

```
Format_Date
---------------
6/15/2014
```