# Is it possible to group by day, month or year with timestamp values?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table `ORDERS(idOrder, idProduct, Qty, OrderDate)` where `OrderDate` is a varchar column with timestamp values, is it possible to get the `Qty` of each day, week, month or year ?

The table looks like this :

```
---------------------------------------
|idOrder | idProduct | Qty | OrderDate|
---------------------------------------
| 1      |  5        | 20  | 1504011790 |
| 2      |  5        | 50  | 1504015790 |
| 3      |  5        | 60  | 1504611790 |
| 4      |  5        | 90  | 1504911790 | 
-----------------------------------------
```

and i want something like this

```
------------------------------
| idProduct | Qty | OrderDate|
-------------------------------
|  5        | 70  | 08/29/2017|
|  5        | 60  | 09/05/2017|
|  5        | 90  | 09/08/2017| 
-------------------------------
```

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using and provide sample data and desired results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

looks like you want to do 2 things here: first group by your idProduct and OrderDate

`select idProduct, sum(Qty), OrderDate from [yourtable] group by idProduct, OrderDate`

This will get you the sums that you want. Next, you want to convert time formats. I assume that your stamps are in Epoch time (number of seconds from Jan 1, 1970) so converting them takes the form:
`dateadd(s,[your time field],'19700101')`

It also looks like you wanted your dates formatted as mm/dd/yyyy. 
`convert(NVARCHAR, [date],101)` is the format for accomplishing that

Together:

`select idProduct, sum(Qty), convert(NVARCHAR,dateadd(s,OrderDate,'19700101'), 101)
from [yourtable] 
group by idProduct, OrderDate`

Comment: O_O ! THANK YOU SOO MUCH

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, the TSQL TIMESTAMP data type isn't really a date. According to [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8119386/how-to-convert-sql-servers-timestamp-column-to-datetime-format) they're even changing the name because it's such a misnomer. You're much better off creating a DATETIME field with a DEFAULT = GETDATE() to keep an accurate record of when a line was created.

That being said, the most performant way I've seen to track dates down to the day/week/month/quarter/etc. is to use a date dimension table that just lists every date and has fields like WeekOfMonth and DayOfYearand. Once you join your new DateCreated field to it you can get all sorts of information about that date. You can google scripts that will create a date dimension table for you.

Comment: Thank you so much, i was going for this solution until @MattDekinder gave me exactly what i was looking for ^^"

Answer (score 0):

Yes its very simple:

```
TRUNC ( date [, format ] )
```

Format can be:

```
TRUNC(TO_DATE('22-AUG-03'), 'YEAR')
Result: '01-JAN-03'

TRUNC(TO_DATE('22-AUG-03'), 'MONTH')
Result: '01-AUG-03'

TRUNC(TO_DATE('22-AUG-03'), 'DDD')
Result: '22-AUG-03'

TRUNC(TO_DATE('22-AUG-03'), 'DAY')
Result: '17-AUG-03'
```

Comment: i am sorry i guess i mislead you when i didnt give a glimpse at how my table look like

Comment: Still TO_DATE and TRUNC is what you need ;)

Comment: I am working with sql server, and TO_DATE is Oracle function i believe ^^"

Comment: Oh I see! In tha case try out  -- Convert the current date to YYYY-MM-DD format
  SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), GETDATE(), 120);