# how to show type timestamp field in select query date time formatted

Tags: datetime, formatting

I've tried:

```
select CAST(ssma_timestamp AS datetime) from sa_project
```

but it does not show date and time correctly

> ssma_timestamp is declared as timestamp

I would like to see it in `mm/dd/yyyy HH:MM:SS` format

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to convert SQL Server's timestamp column to datetime format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8119386/how-to-convert-sql-servers-timestamp-column-to-datetime-format)

Comment: See answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8119407/3677457)