# sql server convert datetime failed

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, datetime

I want to convert this time_stamp column (nvarchar50) into datetime column in SQL server. the value of time_stamp is "2018-02-16 13:30:27+09:00".
I don't know which datetime code should I use to convert it. Can you help?

This is what I tried:

```
select convert(datetime,time_stamp, 110)  from table;
select convert(datetime,time_stamp, 120)  from table;
```

Comment: There may be a way to do this, but an equally convenient way would be to just request your timestamps in UTC time, with no timezone component.

Comment: Check below link
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8119386/how-to-convert-sql-servers-timestamp-column-to-datetime-format

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is failing because of the timezone embedded in the string. However, it will work if you remove the timezone using string function such as `LEFT`.

```
SELECT CONVERT(DATETIME, LEFT(time_stamp, 19), 110)  
FROM tableName
```

Here's a [Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/9900c/1).

Comment: When converting to Datetime , the Style parameter in `Convert( Datetime , Value [, Style ])` function is redundant. SQL server doesn't have any styles for datetime values they are stored in ticks in the database engine behind the scenes.

Answer (score 0):

There is timezone offset in your sample date. If we want to ignore timezone offset then we can use below code -

```
declare @x nvarchar(50) = '2018-02-16 13:30:27+09:00'
select convert(datetime,convert(datetimeoffset, @x))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Declare @dt NVARCHAR(100) = '2018-02-16 13:30:27+09:00'

select CAST(SWITCHOFFSET(TODATETIMEOFFSET( LEFT(@dt , 19) ,RIGHT(@dt, 6)),0) AS DATETIME)
```

Returns:

```
2018-02-16 04:30:27.000
```