# Error Arithmetic overflow error converting expression to data type datetime. while converting timestamp to datetime SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, datetime, type-conversion, timestamp

I am trying to convert timestamp by using,

```
convert(datetime,D.TimeStamp)
```

My timestamp value is like,

```
0x000000000D8B2E9E
```

I am getting this error:

> Msg 8115, Level 16, State 2, Line 121
>   Arithmetic overflow error converting expression to data type datetime.

Hopes for your suggestion

Comment: What is the type of your timestamp and what value is it supposed to represent?

Comment: Take a peek at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8119386/how-to-convert-sql-servers-timestamp-column-to-datetime-format

Comment: i am getting this data i have no idea about its type :(

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to convert SQL Server's timestamp column to datetime format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8119386/how-to-convert-sql-servers-timestamp-column-to-datetime-format)

Comment: that data that starts with 0x is hex and it converts to 227225246. If in epoch it is march 1977. what value do you expect?