# Table has one record per employee per year. What should be the query to change visibility if employee data is not recorded this year

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

My table has one record per employee per year. What should be the query to change visibility if employee data is not recorded this year.

Column names are `employee_name`, `employee_Id`, `rating`, `CreatedOn` where `CreatedOn` is basically timestamp.

Suppose there are two forms, `form1` and `form2` and its visibility depends on the user input. If user has submitted `form1`, he can only see `form2`. Exactly after a year, respective user can see the `form1`again.

I tried the following command, but is not working

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM
TABLE
WHERE employee_Id = '$CurrentUserId$'
AND CreatedOn > DATEADD(year,-1,GETDATE())
```

if `query = 0`, show `form1`, else show `form2`

I know basic SQL, but my skills are not upto this level.

Comment: What is the data type of CreatedOn?

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT CASE COUNT(*) WHEN 0 THEN 'Form1' ELSE 'Form2' END AS ShowForm
FROM
TABLE
WHERE employee_Id = '$CurrentUserId$'
AND CreatedOn > DATEADD(year,-1,GETDATE())
```

Comment: the problem is  `DATEADD(year,-1,GETDATE())` is not working, probably due to `createdon`is saved as timestamp like ''2018-12-16 12:29:56.577"

Comment: `and CreatedOn > DATEADD(year,-1,GETDATE())` works fine in my test, having CreatedOn declared as a `timestamp`. So your problem must be elsewhere

Comment: Use the condition as CAST(CreatedOn AS DATE) > CAST(DATEADD(YEAR,-1,GETDATE()) AS DATE)

Comment: `CreatedOn` cannot be declared as `TimeStamp` in your table. Than `CAST(CreatedOn AS DATE)` will return an error `Explicit conversion from data type timestamp to date is not allowed.`

Comment: TimeStamp in SQL Server has nothing to do with datetime ! See also this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8119386/how-to-convert-sql-servers-timestamp-column-to-datetime-format

Answer (score 0):

When checking if a record exists or not, use `EXISTS` / `NOT EXISTS`. `COUNT()` will actually count all rows while `EXISTS` will short-circuit at the first row, thus being quicker.

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT 'record this year' FROM [TABLE] T WHERE T.employee_Id = '$CurrentUserId$' AND T.CreatedOn > DATEADD(YEAR,-1,GETDATE()))
BEGIN
    -- Do stuff if record this last year
END
ELSE
BEGIN
    -- Do stuff if no record this last year
END
```

If you need this on 1 `SELECT` statement you can use Dheerendra's solution.