# How to convert timestamp to datetime

Tags: sql, sql-server

How to convert datetime to timestamp  ?

Timestamp like `'yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss.mss'` 
I try to format this

```
format(time_field , 'dd.mm.yyyy hh:mm:ss')
```

but in the end it turns out `'1.43.2019 01:43:03'`

Comment: Excuse me, but have you tried writing it ... just the same as you want it ?

Comment: Please Google before posting duplicates: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8119386/how-to-convert-sql-servers-timestamp-column-to-datetime-format

Comment: relevant : [Common mistakes in datetime formatting and parsing](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2015/05/05/common-mistakes-in-datetime-formatting-and-parsing/) by Jon Skeet

Comment: time_field is a misleading _column_ name. Tables have _columns_, not fields. A timestamp has minute, second etc _fields_.

Answer (score 2):

use `MM` for month when formatting

```
SELECT FORMAT(GETDATE(), 'dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm:ss')
```

Comment: May I add to that. If you want 24-hour format you should use `HH` instead of `hh` or append the string with `tt` for AM/PM.

Answer (score -1):

use the built in convert function, with a suitable option.

```
 SELECT CONVERT(varchar, getdate(), 21);
```

https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_sqlserver_convert.asp

Comment: any explanation from the person who decided to thumb this down?  Would be appreciated.

Answer (score -1):

You don't actually need to use `format()` for this, because the format you want is a "built-in" format for SQL Server's [`convert()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/cast-and-convert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) function:

```
select convert(varchar(255), timefield, 120)
```

I'm not a big fan on `convert()` and its arcane formatting options.  However, options 120 and 121 are pretty much the ones that I know and use.