# Trying to save timeStamp recorded in jmeter results from csv to MSSQL server

Tags: sql-server, datetime, jmeter, timestamp

I am not able to save proper timeStamp from JMeter to CSV and same CSV to MSSQL server.

I am saving results right now but they appear in a wierd manner like 1559087654 etc

I want proper format of the timeStamp at what time and date exact results were recorded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to update jmeter.properties file which is present in /bin folder of jmeter location.

Please go through the below screenshot and uncomment the line selected in the screenshot. (Its uncommented in the screenshot)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can import the CSV file to the MSSQL (as a table), then you can covert (cast) the timestamp column to datetime.

Please check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8119386/how-to-convert-sql-servers-timestamp-column-to-datetime-format/8119407#8119407), it may help you

Answer (score 0):

The default items to be saved can be defined in the jmeter.properties (or user.properties) file located under bin folder. Give preference to user.properties. Find the below line in jmeter properties and copy paste it in user.properties in the end of the file. Remove the hash in front. Restart jmeter.

> ## jmeter.save.saveservice.timestamp_format=yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss.SSS

Check [default configuration](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/listeners.html#defaults) for more info.

Hope this helps.