# converting timestamp to date yields wrong hour

Tags: sql, oracle, epoch

I have this timestamp value: 1568387621
I need to convert it to date.

I tried something like:

```
SELECT TO_TIMESTAMP('19700101','yyyymmdd') + ((1568387621/1000)/24/60/60)
FROM dual;
```

But it doesn't work.

My timezione is Europe/Rome.

Some conversion websites tell me the value converted is: 2019-09-13 17:13:41
Instead, in the best case on db I obtain: 2019-09-13 15:13:41

Which hour is correct (15 or 17). How can I convert it correctly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to cover time zone use this one:

```
(TIMESTAMP '1970-01-01 00:00:00 UTC' + 1568387621 * INTERVAL '1' SECOND) AT 'Europe/Rome'
```

Comment: Thank you very much: SELECT (TIMESTAMP '1970-01-01 00:00:00 UTC' + 1568387621 * INTERVAL '1' SECOND) AT time zone 'Europe/Rome' FROM dual; worked fine

Answer (score -2):

SQL Server's TIMESTAMP datatype has nothing to do with a date and time!

Read first answer here:

[How to convert SQL Server's timestamp column to datetime format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8119386/how-to-convert-sql-servers-timestamp-column-to-datetime-format)

Comment: This question is not about SQL Server; it's tagged as Oracle.

Comment: I confirm. It's Oracle not Sql Server