# Get SQL timestamp value by data reader

Tags: vb.net, timestamp, sqldatareader

We have a timestamp type column in our table.

I am trying to retrieve that is vb.net using data reader.

```
datareader.GetValue(dr.GetOrdinal("timestamp")).ToString()
```

It is not showing the value from the database. How should I retrieve the value? or how to cast it correctly?

Comment: You appear to be using two different data readers in that code. Either that is a likely candidate for your problem or you have provided code that is not representative of what you're actually doing. Also, you haven't explained what that code actually does do.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/8119407/8367626

Comment: @Mary good catch. In this case, this is dupe question