# SQl Server timestamp conversion

Tags: sql, sql-server, datetime

I am having a rows of data with the timestamp value as mentioned below:

- 0x00000000120431EB
- 0x00000000120431ED
- 0x0000000012043257
- 0x0000000012043259
- 0x000000001204330D

Is there any possibility to convert them into proper datetime as dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm:ss?

### I tried using cast but ended up with the below errors:

- SELECT CAST(0x00000000120431EB AS date)
- SELECT CAST(0x00000000120431EB AS datetime)

same error message for both the query,

Conversion failed when converting datetime from binary/varbinary string.

### Also have tried convert but ended with error:

- select CONVERT(date,0x00000000120431EB)

Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.

Comment: What does a value sych as `0x00000000120431EB` mean? How was it produced?

Comment: No - the datatype has no relationship to dates or times

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8119386/how-to-convert-sql-servers-timestamp-column-to-datetime-format

Comment: `timestamp` does not mean some kind of time. `timestamp` is a (deprecated) synonym of `rowversion`. You can't convert a `timestamp` to a date and time datatype, as it has nothing to do with dates or times.

Comment: I got this value when i attache the database from a backup.