# Select DATE part from TIMESTAMP in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have this part of a query made in POSTGRE and I want to change it for using it in SQL Server, but there is an error in `DATE()` function.

```
AND DATE(A.SERVERTIME) = DATE(B.SERVERTIME) + 1
```

`SERVERTIME` is `TIMESTAMP` datatype.

I want to know how to get the date part from `SERVERTIME`.

Comment: Are you using SQL Server or PostgreSQL? They are *completely* different products... Please tag correctly. I have removed references to both RDBMS because it's completely unclear which you are talking about.

Comment: Sorry, you are right. I just changed it. I made it in PostgreSQL but now I need this in SQL Server.

Comment: `timestamp` can't be converted to a date (and time) value in SQL Server. `timestamp` is a deprecated synonym for `rowversion`, it's not a date or time at all; it's a `binary(8)`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to convert SQL Server's timestamp column to datetime format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8119386/how-to-convert-sql-servers-timestamp-column-to-datetime-format) TL;DR: You can't.

Comment: I actually found this solution: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/current-timestamp-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15

Comment: `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` returns a `datetime`, @Papillion, not a `timestamp`. That is **very clearly** stated in the documentation you inked, under the [**Return Type**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/current-timestamp-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#return-type) section.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to return only the Date from a SQL Server DateTime datatype](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/113045/how-to-return-only-the-date-from-a-sql-server-datetime-datatype)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want to add days;

```
AND cast(A.SERVERTIME as date)= cast(DATEADD(day, 1, B.SERVERTIME) as date)
```

Edit: As Larnu warned, timestamp can not be casted to date. However it can be casted to date if it goes through DATEADD function.

Hence it should be;

```
AND cast(DATEADD(day, 0, A.SERVERTIME) as date)= cast(DATEADD(day, 1, B.SERVERTIME) as date)
```

Comment: *IF* this works, then: 1. The OP's question is wrong, the column is not a `timestamp`. 2: There are *plenty* of existing questions on how to convert a date and time value to a date (including a [canonical duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/113045/how-to-return-only-the-date-from-a-sql-server-datetime-datatype). 3: As such the question should be closed as a dupe.

Comment: I checked in my environment. 
create table testdate (id integer, ts timestamp);
insert into testdate values (1,DEFAULT);
select *, dateadd(day, 1, ts), cast(dateadd(day, 1, ts) as date) from testdate;

It gives;
id ts (No column name) (No column name)
1 0x00000000000007D2 1900-01-02 00:00:06.673 1900-01-02
--
timestamp cant be converted however it can be converted if dateadd is used.
However you are right, there is some error. left hand should also be worked with dateadd functions. I will edit this thank you.

Comment: The date values from get from the `timestamp` are nonsense values though, @dkc. [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=4766bbc75253d385024ebc743de84f42). *Again*, `timestamp` is **not** a date and time value in SQL Server.